# How can i implement SAML SSO in ios application?

Tags: ios, single-sign-on, saml

I want to implement  SP-initiated SAML SSO  with Http-Post binding for a ios Application

Can anyone suggest me any approach which is feasible and which is adopted by most of the application.

Should the use external web browser or a internal webview for this? Again

1. If i use external web browser how can i get the http POST asserstion
   back to the application.
2. If internal webview how can i get the POST body of SAML assertion ?

*Please let me know if anyone has any suggestions !*

Comment: did u ever found a solution?

Comment: I swiched to OAuth2.0 instead.